# Error in swift 4

Tags: swift

Here is my swift code:

```
while ((mutatedString.range(of: "-")?.lowerBound) != nil) {
        if let range = mutatedString.range(of: "-") {
        let caseString = mutatedString.substring(with: range)
        let caseString = mutatedString.substring(with: <#T##String.CharacterView corresponding to your index##String.CharacterView#>.index(range.lowerBound, offsetBy: 1)..<.index(range.upperBound, offsetBy: 1))
                    mutatedString = mutatedString.replacingCharacters(in: range.lowerBound..<<#T##String.CharacterView corresponding to your index##String.CharacterView#>.index(range.upperBound, offsetBy: 1), with: caseString.uppercased())
                }
            }
```

placeholder editors error..
Thanks.

Comment: Lookup "editor placeholders in text" ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What error? Your code seems to have placeholders...

Answer (score 0):

```
<#T##String.CharacterView corresponding to your index##String.CharacterView#>
```

Is an editor placeholder from autocomplete. You're supposed to replace it with a variable